# Best way to create several lines in a second Sharepoint list based on a template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, template

Dear community members,

I have built a Sharepoint site (Sharepoint 2013) for project management:

- One list with the projects pipeline: description, PM, baseline, client,...
- One list with the tasks/activities for all projects; we use it we "my tasks" or "project" or "client" filter.

Based on the topology of each project (eg. for Client X, or type Y) a specific set of tasks is automatically created via a SharePoint 2010 workflow. Each and every task is coded in the workflow as "Create list item" with several attributes including the heritage of the project pipeline ID in order to be able to link it to my project.

It is working but I'm wondering if the option chosen is the most appropriate considering that:

- If I want a new task to be added in the template, I need to code it in the workflow.
- My workflow item is a huge workflow now with many lines and I'm affraid that it will be complicated to debug it if I have issues in the future.
- In principle I'm wondering if this way to proceed is really appropriate.

Thanks to all for any contribution in this

Regards, 

Tzelos

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow is very huge, I suggest you put your actions into different steps and type a name for each step. When debugging your workflow, debug it based on different steps, like the below:
[image]

In SharePoint 2013, to create items automatically, generally, we can use Event Receiver or Scheduled PowerShell cmdlet or SharePoint workflow.If you use Event Receiver or Scheduled PowerShell, you may need to develop a huge code to achieve your requirement. So, for your requirement, SharePoint workflow should be appropriate, you can create and debug it easier.